# QLPreview and UIApplication?

Tags: events, touch, qlpreviewcontroller

See this: http://milgra.blogspot.com/2012/10/qlpreviewcontroller-in-ios-6.html

> It seems that Apple did some nasty things with QLPreviewController, it
>   started acting like a separate application over the mother
>   application, it intercepts all touch events, and nothing reaches
>   "UIApplication sendEvent:" .  I've tried a lot of things to trick it,
>   subclassing and overriding touch events, adding its view to every
>   possible level, figuring out it's inner structure, adding a
>   semi-transparent overlay view and forwarding touch events, but nothing
>   worked.

I have same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give up Quick Look Framework and substitued UIWebView for QL althogh which doesn't make much sense.